# Use of comma with class name in a variable declaration in C#?

Tags: c#

I can understand the use of the latter one. Can you explain the use of the following comma?

```
private WaveGestureTracker[,] 
    _PlayerWaveTracker = new WaveGestureTracker[6, 2];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaveGestureTracker[,]` means two-dimensional array of `WaveGestureTracker`, and `[6,2]` at the end sets the size of array to *6x2*.

Check out that MSDN article: [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)